# Salesforce rest api INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, salesforce, token, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to connect my asp.net REST api to salesforce. I'm succesfully going through authentification, but when I start to send POST requests, I'm getting an error

**{"errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID","message":"Session expired or invalid"}**

Here is my POST request:

```
    //SFServerUrl = "https://na17.salesforce.com/services/";
    //url = "data/v28.0/sobjects/Account";

            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postBody);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Globals.SFServerUrl + url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Globals.SFCookie];
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            string authToken = ticket.UserData;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
            postStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, sb.ToString());
```

When I'm trying to send GET request - I recieve 200 response. 
Also, I've tried to send a POST Request with the same token from Simple Rest Client and it get's 200 response. I tried to change my "Authorization : Bearer" Header to "Authorization : Oauth", but nothing changed. I also tried to catch this error, get refresh token and send a request again with refreshed token, but nothing changed. Please, help me with this.

Comment: Did you try to intercept the rest api call which your code is making to salesforce. Did you see the actual content of the api call being made through your code? It looks like an issue with your cookie. Either the token is not saved in your cookie or you are not sending it in right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I added Headers after Content. When I switched these lines of code everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) I was able to POST the following JSON to `/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account` and create a new Account.

```
{
    "Name" : "Express Logistics and Transport"
}
```

**Raw Response**

> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
>   Date: Sun, 07 Sep 2014 21:32:06 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: BrowserId=_HC-bzpTQABC1237vFu2hA;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Thu, 06-Nov-2014 21:32:06 GMT
>   Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>   Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=209/15000
>   Location: /services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/0010000000000001AAA
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Encoding: gzip
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> {
>     "id" : "0010000000000001AAA",
>     "success" : true,
>     "errors" : [ ]
>   }

Things to check:

1. Your URL. It appears to be missing the leading `/services`
2. Is `SFServerUrl` the same Salesforce pod/server that the Session Id was issued to? If the Session Id came from another pod then it would be invalid on na17.
3. How did you create the Session Id? If you used OAuth, what scopes did you request?
4. Is the Session Id coming out of the cookie valid?
5. Has something else using the same Session Id called logout and invalidated the session?

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

See also:

- [Using REST API Resources - Create a Record](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm)